# Saving API Data to a file PHP

Tags: php, cron, bitcoin

I am getting price and volume data from six bitcoin exchanges to make a price converter but it is super slow because every time you load the page it has to query all those sites for their data. 
I want to run something in the background every 1 minute that gets the data and saves it to a file on the server and then when a user comes to the site it just grabs it from the file with the already retrieved API data. I've been trying to use file_put_contents to no avail. 
Here is the code I've got so far:

```
<?php

function getData($url) {
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$rawData = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
return json_decode($rawData, true);
}


//BTC Volume LocalBitcoins
$BTCVolumeLocal = getData('https://localbitcoins.com/bitcoinaverage/ticker-all-currencies/');
$LocalVolume = $BTCVolumeLocal["USD"]["volume_btc"];

//BTC Volume BTCE
$BTCVolumeBTCE = getData('https://btc-e.com/api/3/ticker/btc_usd');
$BTCEVolume = $BTCVolumeBTCE["btc_usd"]["vol_cur"];

//BTC Volume Bitstamp
$BTCVolumeStamp = getData('https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/');
$StampVolume = $BTCVolumeStamp["volume"];

//BTC Volume Bitfinex
$BTCVolumeFinex = getData('https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/pubticker/btcusd');
$FinexVolume = $BTCVolumeFinex["volume"];

//BTC Volume OKCoin
$BTCVolumeOK = getData('https://www.okcoin.com/api/ticker.do?ok=1');
$OKCoinVolume = $BTCVolumeOK["ticker"]["vol"];

//BTC Volume LakeBTC
$BTCVolumeLake = getData('https://www.lakebtc.com/api_v1/ticker');
$LakeVolume = $BTCVolumeLake["USD"]["volume"];

//Totals the Volumes
$TotalVolume = $LakeVolume + $FinexVolume + $OKCoinVolume + $StampVolume + $BTCEVolume + $LocalVolume;
//Percents of Total Volume
$BTCEPercent = $BTCEVolume / $TotalVolume;
$StampPercent = $StampVolume / $TotalVolume;
$FinexPercent = $FinexVolume / $TotalVolume;
$OKPercent = $OKCoinVolume / $TotalVolume;
$LakePercent = $LakeVolume / $TotalVolume;
$LocalPercent = $LocalVolume / $TotalVolume;

//BTC Price BTCE
$BTCPriceBTCE = getData('https://btc-e.com/api/3/ticker/btc_usd');
$BTCEPrice = $BTCPriceBTCE["btc_usd"]["last"];

//BTC Price Bitstamp
$BTCPriceStamp = getData('https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/');
$StampPrice = $BTCPriceStamp["last"];

//BTC Price Bitfinex
$BTCPriceFinex = getData('https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/pubticker/btcusd');
$FinexPrice = $BTCPriceFinex["last_price"];

//BTC Price OKCoin
$BTCPriceOK = getData('https://www.okcoin.com/api/ticker.do?ok=1');
$OKPrice = $BTCPriceOK["ticker"]["last"];

//BTC Price LakeBTC
$BTCPriceLake = getData('https://www.lakebtc.com/api_v1/ticker');
$LakePrice = $BTCPriceLake["USD"]["last"];

//BTC Price LocalBitcoins
$BTCPriceLocal = getData('https://localbitcoins.com/bitcoinaverage/ticker-all-currencies/');
$LocalPrice = $BTCPriceLocal["USD"]["avg_1h"];

//BTC Price * Percent
$BTCEPricePercent = $BTCEPrice * $BTCEPercent;
$StampPricePercent = $StampPrice * $StampPercent;
$FinexPricePercent = $FinexPrice * $FinexPercent;
$OKPricePercent = $OKPrice * $OKPercent;
$LakePricePercent = $LakePrice * $LakePercent;
$LocalPricePercent = $LocalPrice * $LocalPercent;

//Bitcoin Price
$bitcoinPrice = round($LakePricePercent + $OKPricePercent + $FinexPricePercent + $StampPricePercent + $BTCEPricePercent + $LocalPricePercent, 2);

?>
```

Comment: the important point is what you do with file_put_contents? the error you got? If you share that information perhaps someone could help you.

Comment: Also, is there a specific reason why you chose file storage instead of a database?

Comment: No specific reason I just thought a file would be easier to work with.

Comment: Dat Pham I tried a bunch of things and none of them worked so I ended up deleting it all. I'm just looking for the easiest way to save the API data be that a database or some sort of file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a couple of projects with various Bitcoin API's and have spent alot of time storing API data for the very same reason of lag.

1.) Put the data into a database,...you're going to go crazy working with flatfiles and this many sources. Doesn't need to be big or complicated, but it's the right tool for the job and will be much more flexible long-term.

2.) A CRON job would be the ideal way to go to trigger the code at whatever interval you'd like. In the past I've used user visits to trigger the processing script and it does work, my experiences doing that lead me to not do that anymore.

In your example, if you don't have a visitor every minute, then every visitor is still going to have to sit through the API calls and the gains are evaporated.  If you do have one or more visitor each minute, then this method is a bit better looking,...but one of those visitors is still going to have to wait.

3.) With the CRON method, you'll have a full log of the API's,...which isn't a bad thing to have. Could make for some useful historical info, covers you if there's ever any API downtime. If it's triggered by the user, you'll have holes in that data and less options in the future.

Good luck.